# How to run terminal commands using Dart HttpRequest?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I need to send a request to the server to run a jar file with a string argument/parameter and return the results as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On server side you can run a process and send result back like this :

```dart
HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 3031).then((server) {
  server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
    var param = request.uri.queryParameters['name'];
    Process.run('java', ['-jar', 'myJar.jar', param]).then((pr) => 
        request.response
          ..write(pr.stdout)
          ..close()
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Please, please make sure that you validate the parameters if you pass data from the web directly to a terminal command, There are enough insecure applications out there.